# installing GWT plugins to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

i started to explore GWT yesterday it self and was going basic tutorial in google documentation, I've downloaded GWT ran a sample project without Eclipse as the tutorial stated and then started to setup Eclipse. 
I'm using Eclipse Galileo and according to given instructions i followed the steps and when i was installing GWT plug-in for eclipse i came across an error, so i re ran the plug-in installation and came across the same error again, this is my **3rd time** of that procedure. so i turned on to you, I've pasted the error messages below, some one please help me out.

regards,
rangana

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed

session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).

Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.5/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.1.3.3_1.3.3.v201004231111.jar.

Read timed out

Unable to read repository at http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.5/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.2.0.3_2.0.3.v201002191036.jar.

Read timed out

Comment: Why did you make this question CW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [alternative installation procedure](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html) (from a zip file)?

Comment: i didn't tried the .zip file installation, i will try it out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the work around :

1. Separately download the jar files for which read timeout is hapenning.
   In this case download 
   com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.2.0.3_2.0.3.v201002191036.jar.
   com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.1.3.3_1.3.3.v201004231111.jar.
   using above url.

   Note: both jars are above 80MB and takes a while for download.
2. copy the jars to plugin folder of eclipse
3. resume plugin installation once again.