# Setting GWT eclipse's plugin

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I am really new to Java. I want to use gwt and so to install gwt eclipse's plugin. So I added the link https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 to install all the dedicated 'new software'. It worked fine. But, when I open a project, the gwt sdk is set to invalid. So no library seems to have been imported. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you set up build path properly?

Comment: @smit I know nothing about build file. Where can I set it ?

Comment: What exactly you want to do? To set up build path follow this link http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm

Comment: @smit I am trying to understand why the gwt sdk is set to invalid though I have successfully downloaded it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903313/installing-gwt-plugins-to-eclipse

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476234/manual-install-of-gwt-2-1-0-in-eclipse-helios-3-6-1

Comment: @smit in fact, I used the alternative mode to install as precised in the post you send me to. And everything seems to have been already correctly installed. But I still have the same message : gwt sdk invalid...

Comment: okay I will try to work on this in my free time.

Comment: Attach some Screenshots. It is pretty hard to figure out the issue without logs or screenshot.

Comment: @user1611830 As sachin said you might only have to configure GWT_HOME classpath as you said earlier you already installed GWT successfully.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily configure GWT externally by 2 options for eclipse.

**Option 1** - For easy maintenance

1) Download the GWT directly from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/downloads/list)
2) In eclipse goto `Windows -> Preference -> Google -> Web Toolkit -> Add` ( Configure GWT version, location and name in popup)

3) You can set up multiple GWT versions and set one of them as default.

[image]

**Option 2**

1) grep/search for gwt-user*.jar in your eclipe folder ( dropins,plugins,features,p2 !!!! )

2) Configure classpath variable GWT_HOME. Goto **"Windows -> Preference -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variable -> New"**

[image]

**Option 3** - Ditch online installation

Install it offline from a zip file . Reference https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip

Comment: I could not install plugin. Its giving me error for "Can not complete Request. Generating Details". I think my eclipse could not resolving the dependencies.

Comment: Updated answer with Option 3 - installing GPE plugin offline. Also ensure you start with fresh eclipse copy to avoid any issue with crashed installation affecting new attempts.

Comment: Can you attach a screen-shot your eclipse classpath and also "Error Log" in eclipse from "Windows -> Show View -> General -> Error Log"

Comment: I attached the screen shot.